# react-router location.pathname such as /users/ that matches both /users/profiles and /users/details. /users/* if you may

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router for programatic navigation in my app. All is fine expect for this new feature I want to add, that requires conditional routing.

I need to render, for instance `profileRoutes` when location is `/users/profile` and `somethingElse` when location is `/users/details` for instance. The code below works fine for now as I only have profileRoutes built. But I consolidated the routes into one, and need `/users/*` or something to that effect, such that that location would match all routes related to /users/...

```
    <Route
    children={({ location }) => (
    <div>
    {
    location.pathname === "/users/profiles" ?
    <profileRoutes></profileRoutes> :
    <otherComponent/>
    }
    </div>
    )}
    />
```

My question: Is there a react-router way to achieve this? like `location.pathname.startswith....` sort of thing?

Comment: make sure you are using startsWith not startWith
i check the situation useLocation().pathname.startsWith('') is working, because useLocation().pathname is a string

Answer (score 0):

For your requirements, please use the parameter `exact`.

**To match either `/users` or `/users/profiles` or `/users/what-ever`:**

```
<Route path="/users" component={Users} />
```

**To match only `/users`**

```
<Route exact path="/users" component={Users} />
```

In principle, let do as follows:

1. In the main component, use `Route` without `exact` to point to
   the component `Users`
2. In component `Users`, use `Route` again to match
   sub-components of `Users`

Here is the example:

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export function RouterExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Main Menu:</li>

          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />

        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Welcome home</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function Users({ match }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Welcome to Users</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Users menu:</li>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${match.url}/profiles`}>User Profiles</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${match.url}/settings`}>User Settings</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <Route exact path={`${match.path}`} component={UserHome} />
      <Route path={`${match.path}/profiles`} component={UserProfiles} />
      <Route path={`${match.path}/settings`} component={UserSettings} />

      <Route path={`${match.path}/:section`} component={UserFooter} />
    </div>
  );
}

function UserHome() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>UserHome Component</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
function UserProfiles() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>UserProfiles Component</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
function UserSettings() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>UserSettings Component</h3>
    </div>
  );
}

function UserFooter({ match }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <hr />
      UserFooter Component is always visible under /users/*
      <br />
      You are now at
      <br />
      path: {match.path}
      <br />
      match params: {match.params.section}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Live demo at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-router-example-7mv62)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction, ie using match!
I didn't need to modify my routes though (I like to keep my components separate and just import instead. I do have an exact tag on the root component, `/`.
Here's what worked for me:

```
<Route
    children={({ match }) => (
    <div>
    {
    match.path == "/users" ?
    <profileRoutes></profileRoutes> :
    <otherComponent/>
    }
    </div>
    )}
    />
```

Now when `match.path == "/users"` is true, all routes downstream ie `/users/etc` are rendered.
Hope this helps someone else!